# Is it possible to change rectangle ordenation in Plotly treemap?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, treemap

I want to make a *treemap* following a predefined ordering, but I don't know how to manipulate the hierarchy defined by `plotly` *treemap*.

Here is the *treemap* I've created:

[image: treemap created]

Here I want the `O` to be above the `U` box and the `UR` to be a unique column, without dividing its space with `NA`.

Here is my code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Treemap(
    labels = ["DR","1,2","D 1","D 2","O","U",
              "3,4,5","P","B","Pe",
              "6,7,8","F","C","Pl",
              "9","UR",
              "10","NA"],
    parents = ["", "DR", "1,2","1,2","1,2","1,2","DR","3,4,5","3,4,5","3,4,5",
               "DR","6,7,8","6,7,8","6,7,8",
               "DR","9",
                "DR","10"],
    marker_colors = ["lightgrey", 
                      "lightblue", "cornflowerblue", "cornflowerblue","goldenrod","green",
                      "lightblue","lightgray","chocolate","cadetblue",
                      "lightblue","grey",'chocolate',"saddlebrown",
                      "salmon","salmon",
                      "burlywood","burlywood",
                      ],
    branchvalues="total"
))

fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=10, l=60, r=25, b=30))
fig.show()
```

Much appreciated!

I've tried creating values for each rectangle, but it didn't help and didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need the argument `tiling`. I think this is what you're asking for.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Treemap(
    labels = ["DR","1,2","D 1","D 2","O","U",
              "3,4,5","P","B","Pe",
              "6,7,8","F","C","Pl",
              "9","UR",
              "10","NA"],
    parents = ["", "DR", "1,2","1,2","1,2","1,2","DR","3,4,5","3,4,5","3,4,5",
               "DR","6,7,8","6,7,8","6,7,8",
               "DR","9",
                "DR","10"],
    marker_colors = ["lightgrey", 
                      "lightblue", "cornflowerblue", "cornflowerblue","goldenrod","green",
                      "lightblue","lightgray","chocolate","cadetblue",
                      "lightblue","grey",'chocolate',"saddlebrown",
                      "salmon","salmon",
                      "burlywood","burlywood",
                      ],
    branchvalues="total",
    tiling = dict(packing='slice-dice')
))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, Kat! Thank you so much for your answer. It helped me a lot. But, I would like to keep D1 on the right side of D2, like my figure and O,U below them like yours. Is it possible?